# Are all integrals of closed contours over an analytic path = $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Now, before anyone grabs their torches and pitchforks, I know that not all integrals of closed contours are $0$.

However, the fundamental theorem of contour integrals tells us that a curve (over an analytic path) only depends on its start point and terminal point, and of course, a closed contour has the same points. Therefore, all closed analytic contours are $0$.

This is obviously wrong, as residues exist for a reason. But, I'm not sure where I'm misunderstanding. Can someone help me sort this out?

EDIT: I guess my question is, why does FToCI fail for some curves?

Comment: The contour integral around a simple, closed curve is $0$ if the function is analytic on _all_ of the enclosed area. This is, for instance, not the case for the unit circle and $f(z) = 1/z$, which gives an integral of $2\pi i$ (if going around the circle counterclockwise).

Comment: See that Arthur's example is not analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: I agree, that is Cauchy-Goursat theorem.

But why does FToCI fail for your example?

Comment: Oh, I'm seeing now that the anti-derivative also has to be analytic on the path. Leave that to my textbook to leave that out. So, given the contour is analytic on the integrand and on its anti-derivative, is the closed contour always 0?

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up: I'm just a student taking a class in complex analysis, so forgive me if I'm wrong as I am not an expert, but I can give a quick simple answer to try to help.

Closed contour integrals of analytical functions are always = 0

When closed contour integrals do *not always* =0 is when the are *not* analytical.  They still can be 0, but can also equal other things like 2*pi*i, but these you figure out by other methods.

To answer your question
I guess my question is, why does FToCI fail for some curves? - Because they are not analytical

I'll update this if I find anything wrong or anything new

Comment: Functions analytic WHERE?